# MLCP load throws DeadLock - MarkLogic 8

Tags: marklogic, database-deadlocks, marklogic-8, mlcp

I am using MarkLogic 8 on 2 RHEL6 servers which are clustered.
I am facing DEADLOCK (Notice) errors while loading data using mlcp. Details:

Data:
500+ CSV files

```
File name Examples:
File1: 20170927_**ABC**_XX_YY.CSV
File2: 20170927_**DEF**_QX_QY.CSV
File3: 20170927_**DE**_QX_QY.CSV
```

Requirement:
I need to load these documents while assigning each CSV to a collection during the load.
So, File1 should belong to ABC Collection, File2 should belong to DEF collection and File3 should belong to DE collection.

Script:
I have tried to achieve this by loading each CSV individually using mlcp.

```
#!/bin/sh
listFiles=`ls -l /location/*.CSV | awk '{print $9}'`
for each in $listFiles
do
     collName=`echo $each | cut -d_ -f2`
     $MLCP_HOME/mlcp.sh import -mode local -options_file connect.txt \
     -input_file_path $each -input_file_type delimited_text \
     -generate_uri -output_collections $collName
done
```

Issue:
Some of the files have got loaded into MarkLogic without any error.
However, I see 'Notice' level DEADLOCK messages in the logs and the loading is stalled.

Question:
I understand DEADLOCK occurs when 2 or more queries(updates) try to achieve lock on a URI which is already holding a write-lock.

1. I was hoping that any number of threads of mlcp load will write data
   into one URI at a time. How is a DEADLOCK possible?
2. Why is it called a DEADLOCK when one query is waiting for the other query to
   complete. Is it not just queuing up?

I see the the following code was given as an example of deadlock in marklogic docs. I do not understand why is it a deadlock. One command is waiting for the other to complete.

```
(: the next line ensures this runs as an update statement :)
if ( 1 = 2) then ( xdmp:document-insert("foobar", <a/>) ) else (),
doc("/docs/test.xml"),
xdmp:eval("xdmp:node-replace(doc('/docs/test.xml')/a, <b>goodbye</b>)",
          (),
          <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
            <isolation>different-transaction</isolation>
          </options>) ,
doc("/docs/test.xml")
```

Comment: Is there an MLCP transform in play? Or maybe CPF or a Trigger?

Comment: No Transforms as you see in the mlcp command. Did not activate CPF/Triggers. It is a plain mlcp load.

Comment: How many rows are in these CSV files? Can you post an example of the URIs that are logging deadlocks? Do the generated URIs match the pattern expected i.e. filename-split-sequence.xml? Do you have directory creation enabled on your content database? https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/17/16/understanding-xdmp-deadlock

Answer (score 2):

I can't really see why you are getting deadlocks. I'd still suspect something outside MLCP is generating those message. Could there be some schedule or just some entirely separate process causing the messages?

I can try to explain deadlocks in respect to MLCP a bit more.

Deadlocks normally occur when you touch a file in update mode, and then spawn, invoke, or eval code that touches the same file. The request that spawns, invokes, or evals hasn't finished yet, so the automatic read or write lock isn't released yet. The subprocess does see the lock and is forced to wait till it gets released. The parent process will be waiting on the subprocess to complete though, so hence the deadlock.

It becomes a little more complex with MLCP, since MLCP will open long-lasting transactions, and will emit multiple calls participating in the same transaction. Those automatic locks will not get released until the entire long-lasting transaction is released. So if MLCP tries to insert the same file twice in the same transaction, that will be trouble.

There might be a way to check if it really is MLCP that is causing the trouble. There are a few command-line arguments that control how many threads are used, and how many requests are included in one transaction. Try using:

```
-transaction_size 1 -batch_size 1
```

Additionally, if you really want to process your files in a sequential manner, add this additionally:

```
-thread_count 1
```

You can run MLCP with just the `import` command (and no other arguments) to get a summary of all the command-line options.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks a bunch @grtjn.
I think I figured it to some extent. I think it is because of the clustered setup I have made.
As mentioned earlier, I had 2 servers which are clustered. But What I did not mention was I have 1 forest each on both the servers. i.e, Forest1 is on server 1 storage and Forest2 is on server2 storage. Further, Both the servers are on different network. 
I removed one forest and I have all running great.
Still, I wonder why the deadlock even with such setup?

Comment: I did add back the clustered server and tried the options -transaction_size , -batch_size and -thread_count.
I see that when I do not mention -thread_count [i.e, when the thread_count is defaulted to 4] , the DEADLOCK occurs.
Seems like more threads in such a setup are causing MLCP to access same document more than once in a single transaction.I find it weird! 
Please help understand the reason.

Comment: You may have found a bug in MLCP. Could you try with latest MLCP? Consider filing a ticket at https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-contentpump if that doesn't help..

Comment: You are right! I was using 8-0-6 version. 9-0-3 (latest) is not throwing such 'Notice' level DEADLOCK errors [very slow though...wonder what is the maximum number of threads I can assign :)]